# ASP : How to get the last index of FB friendlist Json.Parse data?

Tags: json, asp-classic

I use json2.asp in my app.
This is the code to parse friend list json data.

```
Set friendlist = JSON.parse(friendlist_json_data)
```

The result, I can get first friend id with this code

```
friendid = friendlist.data.get(0).id
```

So the friendid = 1234567890 (something like that)

The question is, how to get the last index of friendlist array?

I try to use

```
lastindex = friendlist.data.get.count
```

and

```
lastindex = ubound(friendlist.data.id)
```

but nothing work.

I hope someone will help me because I want to show all user's friends photo profile in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need length of the object called `data`.
Like this:

```
lastindex = friendlist.data.length - 1
friendid = friendlist.data.get(lastIndex).id
```